What would the most efficient method of producing loss runs in this context
I work for an insurance company and we are busy with a project at the moment of automating loss runs. Essentially, a loss run is just a report of a claims history. We are looking at the most efficient way of producing these, with as few touch points as possible to prevent any human error. Essentially, the user will enter a policy number or an assured name. Then, based on whether there is any claims history or not, produce a PDF in a specific template.
Some options we have already looked at are: Creating a dashboard in PowerBI, where the user will pull a data extract and paste it into a Macro enabled excel workbook that will format it and produce a PDF. This is ok in theory but has many touchpoints. We have considered looking at using Powerautomate, but i'm not sure of its capabilities.

Provide a set of sample data and then explain the case you wants to achieve.

I would start with a canvas app, which can store the input in a Sharepoint list (via the 'patch' function). Then, the new list item in the SPO list could trigger a PowerAutomate flow, which's output could be an email, a pdf, etc.
In this approach, the end user use his/hers own account in the canvas app and need at least 'add' privilege in the Sharepoint list. But the flow can run as an adminstrator's account and can have much more privileges.

Use a Power BI Paginated Report.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi
They can be rendered as PDF with high fidelity.
